# How can I add two values in a single column in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating one database in which I am having fields:

`ID`,`NAME`,`EMAIL`,`ADDRESS`,`COLLEGE`

Here I want to add (first name, middle name and surname) in `NAME` and also in `ADDRESS` I want to add (flat_no,street,city,country).

So without creating another table how can I add detail of these fields in same table?

Comment: appending the string result using a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: This will result in a non-normalized table which will give you lots of trouble in the long run. The usual approach in a relational database for such an 1:N relation is to create a second table that holds the addresses for each person. And instead of a single `NAME` column you should have `FIRSTNAME`, `LASTNAME`, `MIDDLE_NAME` columns.

Comment: I think the simple answer is by adding more columns